# LuisResult.Entities.Add causes a System.NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, .net, exception, botframework, azure-language-understanding

In my code I dynamically add entities to a Luis Result like this:

```
[LuisIntent("Show Color")]
public async Task displayColor(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{ 
    EntityRecommendation color;
    if (!result.TryFindEntity("color", out color)) {
        color = new EntityRecommendation();
        color.Entity = "white";
        color.Type = "color";
        result.Entities.Add(color); // <-- This Line Causes the Exception
    }
}
```

The weird thing is this code was working before, but has stopped working and now shows this Exception in the bot emulator when the line `result.Entities.Add(color);` is hit:

[image: Bot Emulator Exception]

[image]

Here is the Exception shown in Visual Studio 2015 :

[image]

Could this be related to wrong Nuget Package versions? It was working smoothly before but I added some Authentication services and now this Exception is showing up. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi Megan did you already try removing the Authentication services and adding things one at a time until you find the culprit/reason?

Comment: @JasonSowers yup! I'm running the bot without auth services right now

Answer (score 0):

Someone answered this question for me on the [BotBuilder repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3168)

> From User @ashicertis
>   I believe that you need to extract the entities object into a new
>   variable and then make changes.
>
> ```
> var entities = new List(result.Entities);
> entities.Add(new EntityRecommendation());
> ```